# Override jQuery validate default settings in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

To override the Query validate plugin, in the [plaugsin document](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), the recommend way is:

```
$(".selector").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
      var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
      if (errors) {
        var message = errors == 1
          ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
          : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
        $("div.error span").html(message);
        $("div.error").show();
      } else {
        $("div.error").hide();
      }
    }
})
```

However, it does not work in MVC4 with jquery-1.7.1.js. it seems jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js prevent the override handle to be called. If do not include this file, the override handle is called and message is displayed. Anybody have the same issue?

Comment: jQuery.validate and Microsofts unobtrusive validation don’t play well together - http://www.tigraine.at/2011/08/26/jquery-validate-and-microsofts-unobtrusive-validation-dont-play-well-together/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally make it work as suggested by [Bruce](http://forums.asp.net/t/1759887.aspx/1). The trick is to remove the old handler before hookup your custom one. You can override other settings the same way. Microsoft should speed up to fix its jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js to work with jquery.validate. It has been reported [unobtrusive [version="2.0.20710.0"] breaks jquery-1.9.0](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776965/please-support-jquery-v1-9-0-properly-in-jquery-validate-unobtrusive).

```
$('form').each(function() {
    $(this).unbind("invalid-form.validate"); // remove old handler!!!!
    $(this).bind("invalid-form.validate", function(e, validator) {
        //alert("ok");
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
                ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
                : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted';
            $("div.error span").html(message);
            $("div.error").show();
        } else {
            $("div.error").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this doesn't work is that the validator has already been created by the unobtrusive plugin, so when you call

```
$(".selector").validate({..})
```

you just get the already created validator instance back and your options are not applied.  However I think you can change the settings this way.

```
<script>
    $(function () {  

        // get the validator instance
        var v = $('form').validate();

        // overwrite the invalidHandler with your own function
        v.settings.invalidHandler = function(form, validator) {
          // your stuff here
        };
    });
</script>
```

Note that this overwrites the 'unobtrusive' invalidHandler function, so you won't get that part of the 'unobtrusive' functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, it does not work for me. The custom handler is not called.