# How to override success behavior for one form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

We are working on `Asp.Net MVC`, using `JQuery Validation` with `Bootstrap` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` to show Success and Error states in our forms. This is more or less the configuration of our defaults:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: "",
        validClass: "has-success",
        errorClass: "has-error",
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {           
                $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);                
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {            
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            }
        }
    });
```

What is the correct way to override this for a specific form on a page? I don't want to fully override the defaults.

This is a change I want to do for only one form in one page (User requested a different behavior). The form doesn't have validators, so it never shows/uses the error style, but when the user selects a value on a field, the "success" style kicks in anyway, and we don't want to show it either.

**What is the correct way to override the highlight and unhilight behaviors for a specific form on a page?**

Comment: If the above code runs, you must be doing `$(form).validate()` somewhere? Just stop doing that if you don't want to validate it

Comment: Crazy question: since you have not mentioned anything about the `.validate()` method, can we assume you're using ASP with the Unobtrusive Validation plugin?

Comment: @adeneo, no we are not calling the .validate() method specifically since we are using unobtrusive validation.

Comment: @Sparky you are right, I totally meant to mention that but slipped my mind, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sparky for helping me understand the issue better!

As he said for most scenarios if you have `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` and you need to override the defaults settings for only one form in a page, you either have to:

- override them for all forms
- or remove the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` and configure each form separately.

However, [following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524880/752842) I realized you can override certain things using the validation object of a form (once created).

The example in the link doesn't work, probably, because by the time he tries to override the event, the original one was already attached.

But in **my** case the **issue could be solved changing the** `validClass` **setting.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get the validator instance
    var validate = $(".my-form").validate();

    // overwrite validClass
    validate.settings.validClass = "";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is:

- `.setDefaults()` is for setting options that will apply to all forms.
- `.validate()` for setting options that will only apply to one particular form.  `.validate()` is used to initialize the plugin on your form and gets called one way or another in all cases.

If you're using ASP with the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, then you are stuck with no solution other than removing the Unobtrusive plugin.  Since Unobtrusive automatically constructs the `.validate()` method, you cannot call it again, as the Validate plugin does not allow this initialization to occur multiple times.  If you try to call `.validate()` yourself while also using Unobtrusive, your `.validate()` call will be ignored.  A typical workaround is to set custom options with `.setDefaults()`, however, as you already have learned, this always applies to all forms on the page.

Comment: Hi Sparty if I understand correctly, so since we are using the jquery.validate.unobtrusive, we are left with 2 options, either set again the defaults in that page (which will override it for all the forms on the page). Or remove the jquery.validate.unobtrusive from that page and manually call the validate({options})  for all its forms?